# Angular re-render on reference change

Tags: angular

I wrote a simple todo app here : https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-framework-i0ef3

on click on the li tag, i update the todo.completed property and the view is updated by applying the 'line-over-text' on the text.

But to me this is not supposed to work, as the todos array reference do not change, and Angular check detection is based on reference change.

Am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good article on Angular change detection:
https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

As I understand, you are creating an event by clicking. After you click, and the object changes, Angular marks the display as changed and updates the DOM as needed